# reloading table view when search bar is empty

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new in swift.I have implement the search operation for json show in table view about description field .

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        // If we haven't typed anything into the search bar then do not filter the results

        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            filteredsneakernews = [classObject.descriptionn]
            self.results = self.placeHolderArray
            self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.reloadData()

        } else {
            // Filter the results
            //filteredsneakernews = [classObject.descriptionn].filter { $0.description.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }
            results = results.filter {
                $0.description.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }
           // self.results = self.placeHolderArray

              self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.reloadData()

        }
       // self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Here is code for table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell") as! DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell


       classObject.getDataForTableView(results: results, index: indexPath.row)
        //let image_url = filteredsneakernews[indexPath.row].image
       // cell.sneakerImageView.image=filteredsneakernews[indexPath.row].image
          self.placeHolderArray = self.results
        cell.newsTitle.text = classObject.descriptionn

        let imageURLPathString = newsurl + classObject.image

        let url1 = URL(string: imageURLPathString)
        print("xyz", url1)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url1!)

        if let imageData = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.sneakerImageView.image = image
        }

        return cell


    }
```

here is the class that i have made for getting data from json

```
class getData: NSObject {

    var descriptionn : String = ""
    var image : String = ""

//    static let shared = getData()

    func getDataForTableView(results: [[String:String]], index : Int){

        var productArray = [String:String]()
        productArray = results[index]

            descriptionn = productArray["description"]!
            image = productArray["images"]!

    }
}
```

The search bar searching the result. when i finish the search **when search bar is empty i want table view should reload the data .it should show the all record in table view when search bar is empty .but it is not reloading table view when search bar is empty** .you can download the code from this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G3QUYLgLDwIjNKb-HB-zO98l14HrcRVe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: on Completing search when search bar is empty table should display all record but it is not showing .   i am using this statement to reload the table view ...        self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.reloadData()....

Comment: Can you show your code for the tableView?

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: `cellForRow` is the wrong place to *getDataForTableView*. Don't do that. And you have to  handle the case *isSearching* in all relevant data source and delegate methods. And the dedicated method for indicating the search is `searchController.isActive`. **Never** check for empty string.

Comment: It looks like your filtering is broken. You are trying to filter for the searchText when no searchText is given. I would bet that there are no results after your filtering inside the results variable. Try to reset your results instead of filtering for a empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ajadka I have seen your code and there is small mistake ...just replace this line n it'll work correctly ..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell") as! DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell
  // self.placeHolderArray = self.results comment this line here 
     ...... }
```

and put that line here

```
 func single_news(userid: Int) {
        .......
    self.results = jsonValue.object(forKey: "data") as! [[String:String]]
    self.placeHolderArray = self.results //put here that line 
     ..........
 }
```